# Retrieving Images from Image Upload using PHP

Tags: php, html, image-processing, phpmyadmin, image-uploading

I'm having issues with displaying images when I upload an image. It inserts all the data into mysql but they don't show up as a previewed image on the localhost. It just shows up as a broken link.

Here is the code I used to insert the image into the database using file upload:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Member System- Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="image" ><br>
<input type="submit">

</form>

    <?php


    //connect to database
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("mysql_error()");
 mysql_select_db("users") or die("mysql_error()");

 //file properties
$file= $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

 if (!isset($file))
 echo "Please select an image";
 else {
$image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_name=addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image_size= getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
 }
if ($image_size==FALSE)
echo "That's not an image.";
else {
    if (!$insert= mysql_query("INSERT INTO images VALUES ('$id','$image_name','$image')"))

    echo "Problem uploading image.";
    else {

        $lastid= mysql_insert_id();
        // create the query
//$sql = "select image from images where id=1";
// the result of the query
//$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Invalid query: " .mysql_error());
// there should only be 1 result (if img_id = the primary index)
//$pic = mysql_fetch_array($result);
// show the image
//echo "Image uploaded. <p/> Your image: <p/> <img src='picture/".$pic['img_name']."' width='300' height='300'/>";
        echo "Image uploaded. <p/> Your image:<p /><img src=<?php get.php?id=$lastid >";


    }




 }



    ?>

Then I called get.php to retrieve the last image id from the database. Here's that code:

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("mysql_error()");
 mysql_select_db("users") or die("mysql_error()");

 $id= addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

 $image= mysql_query("SELECT * from images WHERE id=$id");
 $image= mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
 $image= base64_decode($image['image']);

 ![enter image description here][1]header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
 echo $image;

?>
```

Comment: Do **NOT** use this code. mysql_*() functions are deprecrated, addslashes() is a pathetically USELESS piece of garbage, and you should NOT be storing raw image data in a database without VERY GOOD reasons. Plus, your image is **NOT** being stored in base64 format anyways, so you're decoding invalid data.

Comment: lol why would you addslashes raw data. images should be stored on the server, not in a database. @MarcB drives a really strong point here - don't use this code.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple issues, your image tag looks typo'd

```
<img src=<?php get.php?id=$lastid >
```

even with that corrected, the tag in the HTML page would be:

```
<img src=JFIF0[more binary data here] >
```

when what you probably meant was

```
<img src='get.php?id=<?php echo $lastid ?>' >
```

to produce

```
<img src='get.php?id=3421' >
```

The other issue I see is you are calling addslashes on the binary data before inserting it into the database

and as noted previously, you should consider the mysqli_* series of functions to help protect from sql injection.

Comment: So I'm a little concerned what I should change in order to make the image appear. What code should I take out or insert to fix this issue?

Comment: I think the line causing the broken link is the line that starts `echo "Image Uploaded. ...`   The src attribute of the img element needs to be a URI.  View source on your page with the broken link and see what you are returning there.  And as @Rob W noted, addslashes() is meant for strings, not for binaries.